# sapply with custom function (series of if statements)

Tags: r, apply, lapply, sapply

I want to run a function which looks at two vectors, returning different values depending on the signs of the values in the two vectors. I have written a function which works to compare two values, but then I want to run this on two vectors. So I used sapply, but I am getting different results than expected.

```
bear.correction<-  function(x,y){
                                if(x > 0 && y < 0){
                                  return(90)
                                }else if(x < 0 && y < 0){
                                  return(180)
                                }else  if(x < 0 && y > 0){
                                  return(270)
                                }else   return(0)
                              }
```

The following give the expected (and desired) result:

```
  bear.correction(1,-1)
  bear.correction(1,1)
  bear.correction(-1,1)
  bear.correction(-1,-1)
```

Result: 90, 0, 270, 180

However when I try to do the same comparisons, but using vectors with sapply I get a different result:

```
  x <- c(1,1,-1,-1)
  y <- c(-1,1,1,-1)
  sapply(x,bear.correction,y)
```

Result: 90, 90, 180, 180.

I can't see what's wrong, so please help!

Comment: I'm sorry @agstudy, I thought it was possible to accept multiple answers, but apparently not. I think Stephan Kolossa's answer was the best, though the others all work too, hence my positive comments.

Comment: no problem. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be using `mapply()` instead of `sapply()`:

```
mapply(bear.correction,x,y)
```

Why? Your `sapply()` applies `bear.correction()` to each entry of `x`... but giving it the *entire* `y` vector as a second argument in each case, and so `bear.correction()` only looks at the first entry in `y` in all four cases. To "walk along" multiple entries in *multiple* vectors (or other data structures), use `mapply()`.

Comment: Thanks Stephan. Good answer and clear explanation. I wasn't aware of mapply()

Answer (score 5):

You should be using mapply instead of sapply

```
mapply(bear.correction,x,y)

[1]  90   0 270 180
```

Comment: Thanks, quick and succinct. Stephen gave a nice explanation too.

Comment: For future reference on *apply functions check this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/r-grouping-functions-sapply-vs-lapply-vs-apply-vs-tapply-vs-by-vs-aggrega)

Comment: Thanks. That's a really helpful resource. I will bookmark that.

Answer (score 4):

put a `browser()` in your function like this :

```
bear.correction<-  function(x,y){

  browser()
  if(x > 0 && y < 0){
    return(90)
  }else if(x < 0 && y < 0){
    return(180)
  }else  if(x < 0 && y > 0){
    return(270)
  }else   return(0)
}
```

you will see what give exactly as parametrs :

```
Browse[1]> x
[1] 1
Browse[1]> y
[1] -1  1  1 -1
```

So as others said here you need to use `mapply` to give scalar values, not atomic vector.

but I think here using `plyr` is really simpler (nice output format)

```
library(plyr)
dat <- data.frame(x=x,y=y)
ddply(dat,.(x,y),function(r) bear.correction(r$x,r$y))
   x  y  V1
1 -1 -1 180
2 -1  1 270
3  1 -1  90
4  1  1   0
```

Comment: Thanks, it's useful to have the debugging advice.
The Pylr alternative is nice too. I haven't used pylr much, but it's a good package.

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to use `apply` you have to change a bit your function:

```
bear.correction<-  function(xy){
                                if(xy[1] > 0 && xy[2] < 0){
                                  return(90)
                                }else if(xy[1] < 0 && xy[2] < 0){
                                  return(180)
                                }else  if(xy[1] < 0 && xy[2] > 0){
                                  return(270)
                                }else   return(0)
                              }
```

The function now takes a vector of 2 values `xy` and uses the first like your old `x` and the second like your old `y`

```
x <- c(1,1,-1,-1)
y <- c(-1,1,1,-1)

xyx<-cbind(x,y)


apply(xyx,1, bear.correction)
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a nice solution too.